# Unable to copy to .m2 directory on mac to setup an existing working JAVA project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, setup-project

I am trying to setup a JAVA Springboot project on a mac system. Earlier, it was setup on a windows system.
I am trying to copy the .m2 local repository from that windows system into this one, because some of the repository jars are no more available in the remote repository.

I confirmed via `mvn -version` command that Maven home is `/opt/apache-maven`

However, I cannot cd to .m2 directory inside /opt/apache-maven.

```
SandeepanNath:apache-maven sandeepan.nath$ cd .m2
-bash: cd: .m2: No such file or directory
```

When I run the following commands -

```
SandeepanNath:apache-maven sandeepan.nath$ ls -a
.       ..      LICENSE     NOTICE      README.txt  bin     boot        conf        lib
SandeepanNath:apache-maven sandeepan.nath$ ls -a ~
.           .Trash          .anydesk        .cisco          .m2         .vim            Desktop         Movies          Public
..          .account        .bash_history       .gradle         .oracle_jre_usage   .viminfo        Documents       Music
.CFUserTextEncoding .android        .bash_profile       .grails         .sdkman         .zshrc          Downloads       Pictures
.DS_Store       .anyconnect     .bash_sessions      .grails_history     .ssh            Applications        Library         Postman
```

So, I cannot also copy to the .m2 directory. Any pointers?
It does not look like a permission issue. Anyway, here are the permissions -

```
SandeepanNath:apache-maven sandeepan.nath$ ls -al ~ 
total 152
..
drwxr-xr-x   38 sandeepan.nath  IDC\Domain Users   1216 Jun  3 15:56 .m2
..
```

Comment: Why copying and not simply building your application on Mac?